PC no video, can't restart
My PC just turned off after a blue screen. I didn't have time to read the error code. I tried to turn it on again and while the Windows loading circle was spinning it stayed stuck for a long time, so I decided to restart again, but this time nothing, no video, nothing. There is no image and no power to the peripherals, unless you press a key, then the keyboard turns on and nothing else. The computer fans, including those of the GPU and the processor, are set to 100%.
HERE IS THE MOST IMPORTANT THING I THINK, when I press and hold the power button to turn off the PC, it doesn't turn off or do anything, but the power LED on the front panel starts blinking, just that LED. It seems as if there is some type of short circuit that prevents the PC from turning off. I can only turn it off by pulling the cable or with the PSU switch. Add that the source had been intermittently making a lot of fan noise for several days (without having anything to do with the PC load in terms of cpu or gpu). I have tried everything, disassembled the entire PC, cleaned everything, remounted, rams, gpu, everything.

Ryzen 5600
2070 Super
2x8GB 3200MHz HyperX
PSU NOX 650W 80+ Bronze


Take it to a repair shop for a proper diagnosis.

Your laptop has suffered a hardware failure. It’s probably the motherboard
